Why am I getting a purple boot menu with wrong resolution and half side black after Windows 11 24H2 update?
After installing the Windows 11 24H2 update my Windows boot menu turned purple / violet and the resolution seems wrong with the right side of the screen blank.
After running:
bcdboot c:\windows /v

From my other Windows partition the correct style of the boot menu is restored.
However, running this command from the updated partition the menu turns purple again.
Why does this happen and how can I fix it from the updated system?
Updating my Intel UHD Graphics 620 driver to the latest version before running bcdboot didn't help.


I suggest that you back up your data and then undo the 24H2 update (you only get 10 days to undo the update). You could then try updating the graphics driver and installing 24H2 after that, in case the order of installation makes a difference.

@AndrewMorton I don't think this will make any difference since the old driver didn't show this problem before the update.

You don't have to install 24H2 again, Maybe wait until a new version of 24H2 comes out, as there have been revisions to it.

@AndrewMorton Where can I find the new revisions?

I don't know where or when they are announced :( Did reverting to the previous version make it work properly, if you have done that?

I didn't do this since its too much work and messes up my system.
